# NullPointerException on an existing path

Tags: java, opencv, path, classification

I get a problem while creating a Classifier. My existing path to it causes a `NullPointerException`. I am working with OpenCV 2.4.11 in Eclipse. The OS is Windows that's why I added another backslash between folders. When I insert the path with single backslashes in a file explorer it opens the XML File correctly. My code looks like this:

```
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");
        String path = "C:\\Users\\Juergen\\OpenCV\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
        System.out.println("path:" + path);
        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource(path).getPath());
```

The output is:

```
    Running FaceDetector

    path:C:\Users\Juergen\OpenCV\opencv\sources\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at FaceDetector.main(FaceDetector.java:24)
```

The code is based on the following [instruction](https://blog.openshift.com/day-12-opencv-face-detection-for-java-developers/).

Any ideas on why the NullPointerException is thrown are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `getResource()` might return `null` and calling `getPath()` on that will then give you a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: but why does it turn null? if the file is existing. i check this by         if (new File(path).exists())

Answer (score 0):

When we look at the Java API wi find this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
>   modified_package_name/name

Therefore you must add a '/' in front of your absolute path:

```
String path = "/C:\\Users\\Juergen\\OpenCV\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
```

And you also should get rid of the windows file separator. Java understands the unix file separator and knows how to handle that on a windows system:

```
String path = "/C:/Users/Juergen/OpenCV/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
```

---

> I replaced my string by Yours, nothing changed. Still get a NullPointerException. The check
>
> ```
>  if (!new File(path).exists()) { throw new FileNotFoundException("Yikes!");}
> ```
>
> does not throw any Exception – Jürgen K

Then from the `*.class.getResource(path)` you get an `URL` and from the `URL`'s `getPath()` method you get a `String` which should most likely be the same as your original string.

Did you try to use it directly (with the leading '/')?

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I replaced my string by Yours, nothing changed. Still get a NullPointerException. The check         if (!new File(path).exists())
        {
           throw new FileNotFoundException("Yikes!");
        } does not throw any Exception

Comment: @ Timothy: yes the usage of the leading '/' did not help at all